# What is equivalent of DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain in C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

While using `S3Client` in java, I used to initialize S3Client like this and it worked perfectly on local machine (where I have environment variables set) as well as EC2 instance (where I have IAM role):

```
AWSCredentials credentials = DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance().getCredentials();
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
```

I want to do the same in C#.net. For that, I have to use different methods to run it on local machine and EC2 instance.
Right now, I am doing it somewhat like this :

```
var awsCredentials = new EnvironmentVariablesAWSCredentials(); //For local
var awsCredentials2 = new InstanceProfileAWSCredentials(); //For EC2 instance 
var awsRegion = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_REGION");
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials, RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(awsRegion));
```

I have gone through official [AWS SDK for .Net's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html)

But what I can not find is, equivalent of this `Java Method`

`DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance().getCredentials()`

Is there any method in C#.net that follows hierarchy of retrieving credentials and provide it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is very simple:

Use an empty constructor for all `AmazonClients` (`AmazonSQSClient/AmazonSNSClient/AmazonS3Client`) or use constructor without `AWSCredentials` argument.

So code looks like this :

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
```

OR

```
var awsRegion = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_REGION");
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(awsRegion));
```

Documentation of empty constructor reads like this :

> Constructs AmazonS3Client with the credentials loaded from the application's default configuration, and if unsuccessful from the Instance Profile service on an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

Although the above answer is correct in terms of instantiating an AmazonS3Client(), if you need to get the key for an other reason. For example to calculate the signature for AWS Signature Version 4. Then you can use the following:

```
var instance = new Amazon.Runtime.InstanceProfileAWSCredentials();
var creds = instance.GetCredentials();
var accessKey = creds.AccessKey;
var secretKey = creds.SecretKey;
```

I found this class by looking at the java source on github, and then search the c# source for the same constants when I ran into a similar issue:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/dd8d1fb91763f378cec2e162c03e881cc2fd83e9/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Credentials/_bcl%2Bnetstandard/InstanceProfileAWSCredentials.cs

This is basically making a http request to a service exposed locally on EC2 instances called *"Instance Metadata"*, which also what the java one is calling. **So this code will only get the credentials on an EC2 instance**, if it is run anywhere else you'll get a network exception.

Here is a post on using the service in general:
https://blog.gruntwork.io/authenticating-to-aws-with-instance-metadata-b6d812a86b40

I'm sticking this here as an answer for if you need the key for an other reason than the OP, as this is the top result when you google getting the credentials on an EC2 instance with an IAM role attached.

Comment: For your use case you might want to look into Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory, https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Credentials/FallbackCredentialsFactory.cs, to get the credentials. It is what the constructors that don't take in credentials use to determine credentials in the environment.

Answer (score 1):

The question is old but I just had it now and there is not a lot of good info out there.
There is something similar to Java's DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain in .NET [`FallbackCredentialsFactory.cs`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Credentials/FallbackCredentialsFactory.cs). It is used by default constructor that was properly mentioned in previous answer. If you look into source of a client, for example [`AmazonDynamoDBClient.cs`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/DynamoDBv2/Generated/_bcl45/AmazonDynamoDBClient.cs) you'll see that this factory is what provides "credential provider lookup with fallback" logic.

This can be helpful for example with some 3rd party libraries that for whatever reason require you to explicitly provide credentials (looking at you, [EfficientDynamoDB](https://github.com/AllocZero/EfficientDynamoDb))

This is a very very nice write up about how credential loading is done in AWS SDK for .NET: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/credential-loading-and-the-aws-sdk-for-dotnet-deep-dive